# Why Is my setting of font size in my Excel Interop code over[ridden,written]?

Tags: c#, excel, fonts, excel-interop, named-ranges

I set the font size for a range in my code:

```
var rowRngRptTitle = _xlSheet.Range[_xlSheet.Cells[2, 1], _xlSheet.Cells[2, 13]];
rowRngRptTitle.Merge(Type.Missing);
rowRngRptTitle.Font.Size = 24;
rowRngRptTitle.Font.Bold = true;
rowRngRptTitle.Value2 = String.Format("Delivery Performance - {0} - {1}", _delPerfBeginDate.ToShortDateString(), _delPerfEndDate.ToShortDateString());
```

...but the value does not take effect, or "stick" - the font size is small (it looks like 10, the same as that in a non-configured range).

However, if I set it later, after the entire sheet has been programmatically written, by creating a new range:

```
var rowRngRptTitle2 = _xlSheet.Range[_xlSheet.Cells[2, 1], _xlSheet.Cells[2, 13]];
rowRngRptTitle2.Merge(Type.Missing);
rowRngRptTitle2.Font.Size = 24;
rowRngRptTitle2.Font.Bold = true;
```

...it works - the font size is indeed 24 rather than 10.

What could be canceling out the early setting of the size? There is no other "Font.Size = " in the entire code that refers to that range. In some more context, here is the code (with unnecessary effluvia elided):

```
private void PopulateSheet(string shortName)
{
    if (_xlSheet != null)
    {
        var rowRngUnitName = _xlSheet.Range[_xlSheet.Cells[1, 1], _xlSheet.Cells[1, 13]];
        rowRngUnitName.Merge(Type.Missing);
        rowRngUnitName.Font.Bold = true;
        rowRngUnitName.Font.Size = 16;
        rowRngUnitName.Value2 = shortName;

        var rowRngRptTitle = _xlSheet.Range[_xlSheet.Cells[2, 1], _xlSheet.Cells[2, 13]];
        rowRngRptTitle.Merge(Type.Missing);
        rowRngRptTitle.Font.Size = 24;
        rowRngRptTitle.Font.Bold = true;
        rowRngRptTitle.Value2 = String.Format("Delivery Performance - {0} - {1}", _delPerfBeginDate.ToShortDateString(), _delPerfEndDate.ToShortDateString());

        . . .

        _xlSheet.Columns.AutoFit();
    }
    FreezePane(FIRST_DATA_ROW, SUN_ORDERS_COLUMN);

    var rowRngRptTitle2 = _xlSheet.Range[_xlSheet.Cells[2, 1], _xlSheet.Cells[2, 13]];
    rowRngRptTitle2.Merge(Type.Missing);
    rowRngRptTitle2.Font.Size = 24;
    rowRngRptTitle2.Font.Bold = true;

    ConfigureForPrinting(_xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count);

    if (null != _xlSheet)
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_xlSheet);
    }
}
```

It would be a pain if I have to re-designate ranges wherever I want a different-than-standard/generic/default font size; is there a way to retain the initial font size assignment for the range?

I initialize the Excel app this way:

```
private void InitializeExcelObjects()
{
    _xlApp = new Excel.Application
    {
        SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1,
        StandardFont = "Calibri",
        StandardFontSize = 10
    };

    _xlBook = _xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
    _xlApp.Windows.Application.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = false;

    _xlSheets = _xlBook.Worksheets;
    _xlSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)_xlSheets.Item[1];
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that subject code block is being entered by setting a breakpoint?

Comment: Yes, and all the code shown above is in the same method (PopulateSheet())